# cannot build an '$or' query in node.js with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to append an $or query conditionally, but the query cannot receive the data which I want to search in the db

It just keeps telling me:

> "Error :MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array"

or if I initialize the query.$or as {}

> "Error :MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $or needs an array"

Thank!

For example:

```js
var user = {
      name:"Toby",
      gender:"Female",
      contact:[
        {email:"123@gmail.com"},
        {email:"APPLE@gmail.com"},
        {email:"news456@gmail.com"}]};
var query = {};
var q = ['123@gmail.com','news456@gmail.com'];
query.name = user.name;
if(user.contact!=null){
  query.$or = [];
  query.$or['contact.0.email'] = q[0];
  query.$or['contact.1.email'] = q[1];
}
```

Comment: The SQL command like that: SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='123@gmail.com' OR email='news456@gmail.com' AND name='Toby'

Comment: Thank for your answer! And another solution found too:query1.contact={$elemMatch:{email:{}}};query1.contact.$elemMatch.email.$in=q;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$or needs to be an array of possible match conditions.  You could do:

```
var user = {
      name:"Toby",
      gender:"Female",
      contact:[
        {email:"123@gmail.com"},
        {email:"APPLE@gmail.com"},
        {email:"news456@gmail.com"}]};
var query = {};
var q = ['123@gmail.com','news456@gmail.com'];
query.name = user.name;
if(user.contact!=null){
  query.$or = [];
  query.$or.push({'contact.email': q[0]});
  query.$or.push({'contact.email': q[1]});
}
```